# Failing to install Ubuntu 18.04 in as a guest in VirtualBox 6.1.0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am trying to do something really simple but I am having a problem when doing it. I need to install Ubuntu 18.04 as a guest OS in VirtualBox in order to practice Linux material.

The thing is, I created the new virtual machine, selected basic configurations and used the iso file to install the SO.

However, Ubuntu is freezing just in the beginning of the installation.

So far, I have:

1. Re-installed VirtualBox from the beginning.
2. Download the iso file from scratch in order to make sure it was not corrupted.
3. Store the virtual machine in a brand new partition instead of the external disk I was using.

Here I paste some logs so that you can see more detail:

```
00:00:12.910612 VMEmt: Halt method global1 (5)
00:00:12.910798 VMEmt: HaltedGlobal1 config: cNsSpinBlockThresholdCfg=50000
00:00:12.910846 Changing the VM state from 'CREATING' to 'CREATED'
00:00:12.912990 Changing the VM state from 'CREATED' to 'POWERING_ON'
00:00:12.913140 AIOMgr: Endpoints without assigned bandwidth groups:
00:00:12.913155 AIOMgr:     V:\Ubuntu\Ubuntu 18.04\Ubuntu 18.vdi
00:00:12.913612 Changing the VM state from 'POWERING_ON' to 'RUNNING'
00:00:12.913646 Console: Machine state changed to 'Running'
00:00:12.924941 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: VirtualBox 6.1.0
00:00:12.925598 PCI: Setting up resources and interrupts
00:00:13.121290 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_VM_ERROR (0x80bb0003) aIID={4680b2de-8690-11e9-b83d-5719e53cf1de} aComponent={DisplayWrap} aText={Could not take a screenshot (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=-37
00:00:13.121461 PIT: mode=2 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:13.162380 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=720 h=400 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:13.223328 VMMDev: Guest Log: CPUID EDX: 0x178bfbff
00:00:13.226063 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#1: RESET, DevSel=0 AIOIf=0 CmdIf0=0x00 (-1 usec ago) CmdIf1=0x00 (-1 usec ago)
00:00:13.226223 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#1: finished processing RESET
00:00:13.244150 AHCI#0: Reset the HBA
00:00:13.244172 VD#0: Cancelling all active requests
00:00:13.245384 AHCI#0: Port 0 reset
00:00:13.245573 VD#0: Cancelling all active requests
00:00:13.251466 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: AHCI 0-P#0: PCHS=16383/16/63 LCHS=1024/255/63 0x0000000001400000 sectors
00:00:13.274985 PIT: mode=2 count=0x48d3 (18643) - 64.00 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:13.291284 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=000000000d730000 w=640 h=480 bpp=32 cbLine=0xA00 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:13.414728 GUI: UIMachineViewNormal::resendSizeHint: Restoring guest size-hint for screen 0 to 800x600
00:00:13.423477 GUI: 2D video acceleration is disabled
00:00:13.423664 GUI: HID LEDs sync is enabled
00:00:13.463045 GUI: UIMachineLogicNormal::sltCheckForRequestedVisualStateType: Requested-state=0, Machine-state=5
00:00:15.758858 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=000000000d730000 w=640 h=480 bpp=0 cbLine=0x280 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:15.791080 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=720 h=400 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:15.832294 PIT: mode=2 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:15.835115 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot : bseqnr=1, bootseq=0231
00:00:15.837144 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from Floppy 0 failed
00:00:15.839480 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot : bseqnr=2, bootseq=0023
00:00:15.846642 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Booting from CD-ROM...
00:00:16.091404 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=000000000d730000 w=640 h=480 bpp=16 cbLine=0x500 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
```

- I am assigning 4GB of memory to the guest OS.
- Enable I/O APIC is marked.
- Hardware Clock in UTC Time is marked.
- 2 CPU are assigned to the guest OS.
- Paravirtualization Interface: Default
- Hardware Virtualization: Enable Nested Paging is marked.
- Video memory: 128MB
- Graphics Controller: VMSVGA
- Enable 3D Acceleration is unmarked.
- Enable 2D Video Acceleration is unmarked.

I would have liked to post images here but I was not allowed due to my low reputation (quite new here).

Any comment is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have this machine running fine in VMware Workstation V15.5. Are you sure BIOS has VT-x Enabled (need for 64-bit guests and the default download for Ubuntu 18.04 is 64-bit.

Comment: Hi John! BIOS from host OS has Virtualization enabled. I could not find "VT-x" exactly. Furthermore, I could successfully install Ubuntu as a virtual machine yesterday but I had to remove that machine and create it again. So now I'm having this problem. I really don't know what else to do. I think I will download VMware and try with that one... Thanks.

Comment: As noted, I do have Ubuntu 18 running very well here.